# Ruby - command exit error

Tags: ruby, exit, gets, chomp

I'm completely new to programming and im having trouble figuring out why Im getting an error when typing the following:

```
puts "What is your favorite number?"
number = gets.chomp
number = number.to_i + 1
puts "I suggest " + number.to_s + " as a bigger and better number"
```

When I run in terminal the following error appears:

```
Last login: Fri Jul 10 07:56:21 on ttys000
mba-3093:~ knalavadi$ 
/var/folders/cv/tm657j1d0kg68fbb1rqtrlgjlg_hrm/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/ruby2-458233138.705.rb.command ; exit;

What is your favorite number?
```

Comment: It looks like your Ruby installation is mangled somehow. Are you using the system Ruby or is using something like [RVM](http://rvm.io/) or [RBenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) an option?

Answer (score 1):

The code works. How are you running the script? Put it in a file like number.rb and then run it by typing `ruby number.rb`

Comment: This is more of a  comment than an answer. Maybe you can expand on it a little?